# Can Roxygen ignore non-user functions?

Tags: r, roxygen

I've just started playing around with the `roxygen` package and I've very happy with the results so far.  However I was wondering, is there a way to specify to `roxygen` that it should ignore certain functions that are not user-accessible?

Specifically, I'd rather not have a `.Rd` file pop up because I'm using the `.onLoad()` hook in my package.  This function is already documented in the `base` package so there's no reason for me to re-document it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I finally found and browsed the Roxygen-devel list at [R-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/roxygen/) to see when this would be implemented, and it appears to already be in the version of Roxygen that is on CRAN.  The key is to specify `use.Rd2=TRUE` when calling `roxygenize()`.  Under this mode, Roxygen will skip creating documentation for any functions that are not preceded by Roxygen comments.

Comment: In roxygen2, you can also use `@noRd` to suppress the creation on Rd files even if you have roxygen2 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is on their to do list - in the next version, only functions with roxygen documentation will create man files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal keyword field (*i.e.* `@keywords internal`) to remove the function from the documentation and make it available for experienced users only.
Source: [roxygen2 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html).