# Roxygen, package building, and use.Rd2=TRUE

Tags: r, roxygen

I have a simple shell script that builds my Roxygen documents, builds the package, checks, then installs the newly built package on my machine. It's quite simple:

```
#! /bin/sh
R CMD roxygen -d myPackage 
R CMD build myPackage/
R CMD check myPackage_0.01.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL myPackage myPackage_0.01.tar.gz
```

But I'm having issues with Roxygen picking up my .onLoad() function as [described previously on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2316356/37751). The solution is to use the use.Rd2=TRUE option with roxygenize. Well I want to build from the command prompt so I changed this line

```
R CMD roxygen -d myPackage
```

to the following line which shoves a roxygenize line to R through the stdin:

```
echo 'require("roxygen"); roxygenize("myPackage", roxygen.dir="myPackage",
   copy.package=FALSE, use.Rd2=TRUE)' | R --no-save < /dev/stdin
```

This **seems** to work just dandy. But it feels a little convoluted. Is there an easier and/or more elegant way?

Comment: If it works, what's not to like?

Comment: well I recall once fixing an rJava problem by manually editing the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Although that worked, it seems it was suboptimal. So I thought I would make sure I was not repeating a similar mistake.

Comment: I use a Makefile that basically executes the same thing.  Like Dirk said if it works it works... but if it ain't broke some programmer will usually try to fix it anyway. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar, but I use a HERE document in the shell script to make it look cleaner.

```
#!/bin/sh
##
##
## Must be run from the parent of the package directory (no options
## to change target of check or tarball!?!)

PACKAGE="analyzeNMON"
VERSION=$(awk -F": +" '/^Version/ { print $2 }' ${PACKAGE}/DESCRIPTION)

R --no-restore --slave <<EOR
  library(roxygen)
  roxygenize(package.dir="${PACKAGE}",
             roxygen.dir="${PACKAGE}",
             use.Rd2=TRUE,
             overwrite=TRUE,
             copy.package=FALSE,
             unlink.target=FALSE)
EOR

R CMD build ${PACKAGE}
R CMD check ${PACKAGE}_${VERSION}.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL ${PACKAGE}_${VERSION}.tar.gz
```

The R code is very similar to that in the script run during `R CMD roxygen`.

The roxygen that is installed on my system (version 0.1; installed from CRAN this week) doesn't seem to support the `-s` option mentioned above...

Answer (score 2):

May be the `R CMD roxygen -s` option will help here. I believe it is effectively the same as setting `use.Rd2=TRUE` in the `roxygenize` function.