# CRAN submission - How should I document hidden functions in R?

Tags: r, devtools, cran, roxygen2

Long story short:

My aim is to submit a R package developed with `roxygen2` to CRAN, and I need to find some guidelines on writing and documenting hidden functions.

More details:

I am writing my first R package using `roxygen2` in Rstudio. I have documented all the functions I wrote so far, so that my collaborators can easily understand their purpose before going into the details of the script. All the functions that are of no use to the user, but necessary to the package, are not exported in the namespace and eliminated from the package manual/index (`@keywords internal`). At the same time, my collaborators can still read their documentation using the help of Rstudio.

Eventually, I would like to remove the documentation of these "hidden functions" from the help because there is no reason to keep it. I was considering to follow a suggestion I found in other posts, that is changing `#'` with `##` in the documentation created with `roxygen2`. However, I am not sure this is the correct procedure to implement, and if removing the documentation of a function in the help and the manual is compatible with CRAN requirements.

Can anyone point me to some guidelines related to this issue, or has any experience to share?

Comment: Why not use the version control software, such as git or svn?

Comment: I agree with you, that would have been easier. Unfortunately that wasn't a possibility when we began.
However, that doesn't reply to the question. Can I get rid of the documentation of functions not exported in the namespace or not for CRAN?

Comment: `@noRd` might be useful … (and I just found a SO answer that discusses it https://stackoverflow.com/q/2316356/1457051)

Comment: Only exported functions need to be documented. `R CMD check {pkg}_{version}.tar.gz --as-cran` will tell you whether you're doing something wrong.